# SQL Server call function with dynamic name (from variable for example)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a function which get data from table

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fxnExample (@Id integer)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
       (SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE Id = @Id)
```

And then I call this function in stored procedure, which contains parameters too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT * 
     INTO #ttable 
     FROM @FUNCTION_NAME(@Id);
END
```

I need to call this stored procedure and use data from my function inside. Also I need pass parameters in function that I got in stored procedure.

How can I do it? help me please

Comment: Use `Dynamic SQL` and instead of `into` Clause create the temp table and use `Insert into..` in dynamic query

Comment: @FUNCTION_NAME is also parameter to the sp??

Comment: Yes, it is parameter

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic sql inside your proc

```
declare @sqlText varchar(max)
set @sqlText = 'SELECT * INTO #ttable FROM ' + @FUNCTION_NAME + '(' + cast(@Id as varchar) + ')'
exec(@sqlText)
```

Comment: Just a heads up on this answer -- if you don't completely control the value of `@FUNCTION_NAME` (eg. it comes, in any way, from user input), this can very quickly become a SQL injection vulnerability.  I've use this in scripts to generate tables/views/etc, where I control all inputs, but don't use this in a web app/roll your own escape function/etc.

Comment: You are right. Wherever we use dynic sql, we should consider the risk of sql injection